# Writing the Dijkstra Algorithm in Mathematics

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, article-writing

I would like to know about writing the Dijkstra Algorithm *properly and efficiently* using mathematical notation, which may simplify the process to writing the proof. Assume that the graph is unweighted, and there is no loop. Thanks.

---

### Here is my attempt :

Let $G$ be the whole unweighted multigraph with no loop, $E_{G}$ and $N_{G}$ be the set of all edges and the set of all nodes of $G$ respectively, and $|N_{G}|=m$. Let $n_{0} \in N_{G}$ be the start node, we will search for all shortest paths from $n_{0}$ to all other nodes in $N_{G} - \{n_{0}\}$. Let $j \le m-1$ be a natural number and all nodes in $N_{G} - \{n_{0}\}$ that are connected to $n_{0}$ are labeled as $n_{i}, \: i =1,2,...,j$. Let $N_{c} = \{n_{0}, n_{1}, ..., n_{j} \}$.

Let $p_{n_{i}}^{t}, \: i = 1, 2,..., j$ be the path from $n_{0}$ to node $n_{i}$ after the $t_{th}$ iterations in Dijkstra algorithm. The Dijkstra Algorithm works as follows:

1. Initially, let the paths $p_{n_{i}}^{0}$s be the longest paths.
2. ***1st iteration:*** Now let $N_{n_{0}}$ be the set of all neighbors of $n_{0}$. Let the neighbor nodes be $\{f_{11}, ..., f_{1 \alpha_{1}}\} \subseteq \{ n_{1}, ..., n_{j} \}$, $1 \le \alpha_{1} \le | N_{c} - \{ n_{0} \} |$. Let $e_{n_{0}}^{f_{11}}$ be an edge that connects $n_{0}$ and $f_{11}$. Now because $(e_{n_{0}}^{f_{11}})$ is a shorter path than the longest path $p_{f_{11}}^{0}$, we will set $p_{f_{11}}^{1} = (e_{n_{0}}^{f_{11}})$. By the same reasoning, we also set
   $$p_{f_{12}}^{1} = (e_{n_{0}}^{f_{12}})$$
   $$...$$
   $$p_{f_{1 \alpha_{1}}}^{1} = (e_{n_{0}}^{f_{1 \alpha_{1}}})$$
   The remaining $p_{n_{i}}^{1}$s will be equal to the previous paths (not updated, $p_{n_{i}}^{1} = p_{n_{i}}^{0} $) which is longest path. Now let $X_{1} = \{n_{0}\}$ be the set of all \textit{visited} nodes after the 1st iteration.
3. ***2nd iteration:*** Now note the *unvisited* neighbor nodes of each node in $N_{n_{0}}$ (each neighbor must be in $N_{c} - X_{1}$). The sets of neighbors are $N_{f_{11}}, N_{f_{12}}, ... , N_{f_{1 (\alpha_{1}-1)}}, N_{f_{1 \alpha_{1}}}$. Let the neighbor nodes be denoted as: 
   $$N_{f_{11}} = \{f_{21}, ..., f_{2 \alpha_{2}}\} \subseteq \{ n_{1}, ..., n_{j} \}$$
   $$N_{f_{12}} = \{f_{31}, ..., f_{3 \alpha_{3}}\} \subseteq \{ n_{1}, ..., n_{j} \}$$
   $$...$$
   $$N_{f_{1 \alpha_{1}}} = \{f_{(\alpha_{1}+1)1}, ..., f_{(\alpha_{1}+1) \alpha_{\alpha_{1}+1}}\} \subseteq \{ n_{1}, ..., n_{j} \}$$ Now we can set/update the paths:

   - For neighbors of $f_{11}$ ($N_{f_{11}}$): Let $e_{f_{11}}^{f_{21}}$ be an edge that connects $f_{11}$ and $f_{21}$. Now check whether or not the path $(e_{n_{0}}^{f_{11}},  e_{f_{11}}^{f_{21}})$ is shorter than the path $p_{f_{21}}^{1}$. If it is, then $p_{f_{21}}^{2} = (e_{n_{0}}^{f_{11}},  e_{f_{11}}^{f_{21}})$. But if not, then $p_{f_{21}}^{2} =p_{f_{21}}^{1}$. Do the same process for $p_{f_{22}}^{2}, ... , p_{f_{2 \alpha_{2}}}^{2}$.
   - Do the same process for the neighbors of $f_{12}, ..., f_{1 \alpha_{1}}$.
   - For $ \forall x \in N_{c} - (N_{f_{11}} \cup ... \cup N_{f_{1 \alpha_{1}}}) $, the remaining $p_{x}^{2}$s will be equal to the previous paths (not updated, $p_{x}^{2} = p_{x}^{1} $)
   - Now let $X_{2} = X_{1} \cup \{ f_{11}, ..., f_{1 \alpha_{1}} \}$ be the set of all *visited* nodes after the 2nd iteration.

---

4. ***Next iterations:*** Same process as the 2nd iteration, but we have to consider the neighbor nodes of each node in the set $N_{f_{11}} \cup ... \cup N_{f_{1 \alpha_{1}}})$ (each neighbor must be in $N_{c} - X_{2}$). Repeat this process until we arrive in the $i_{th}$ iteration in which the set of all *visited* nodes $X_{i}$ equals to $N_{c}$. The paths $p_{n_{1}}^{i}, ..., p_{n_{j}}^{i}$ are the shortest paths.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a [something search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=dijkstra%20algorithm%20proof) for "dijkstra algorithm proof" brings up a lot of result, in particular [this Stack Exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835871/dijkstra-algorithm-proof) and [this webpage](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/software/AlgAnim/dij-proof.html), which both have short, concise proofs. The former uses induction, and the latter contradiction. (I haven't read them carefully; they may be in essence the same.)